# Stripping headers from CSV data when converting to XML in Python

Tags: python, csv, elementtree

I'm learning how to parse CSV files and format the data into XML files using ElementTree and minidom (for pretty printing). I've gotten so close, but hit one little snag that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I have the following code:

```
for csvFile in directory:
    root = Element('Order')
    with open(csvFile, 'rt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            queue = row[0]
            token = row[1]
            current_order = SubElement(root, 'Token', {'text':token})
            details = SubElement(current_order, 'Queue',
                                 {'queue':queue})

    print prettify(root)
```

Which produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Order>
  <Token text="token">
    <Queue queue="site_code"/>
  </Token>
  <Token text="H54FC9">
    <Queue queue="Duplex_N-up"/>
  </Token>
</Order>
```

How can I strip the headers from the CSV input so that the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Order>
  <Token text="H54FC9">
    <Queue queue="Duplex_N-up"/>
  </Token>
</Order>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to discard the first line from your csv file?  If so, you can do that pretty easily:

```
for csvFile in directory:
    root = Element('Order')
    with open(csvFile, 'rt') as f:
        junk = next(f)         #read the first line, don't do anything with it.
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            queue = row[0]
            token = row[1]
            current_order = SubElement(root, 'Token', {'text':token})
            details = SubElement(current_order, 'Queue',
                                 {'queue':queue})

    print prettify(root)
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, especially if the column headers are supposed to be identical to the names of the XML nodes, use a `DictReader`, which will read the first row as headers instead of values, and then let you do `row['Queue']` instead of `row[0]`, etc. (which can be a useful check to make sure the columns are what you expected, or a way to do something more flexible where the XML output differs for different-shaped CSV files).

Comment: @DrydenLong It's a matter of taste but I'd go for `for row in islice(reader, 1, None)` as I find that more obvious I'm deliberately skipping a row, and can easily be changed to skip multiple rows if need be.

Comment: Thank @Jon Clements, that makes sense. I like the ability to adjust the amount of rows being skipped.

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV files **always** has a header, call `reader.next()` right after `reader=csv.reader(f)`

Comment: @mgilson: +1. Using `next(reader)` also means your code works with both Py2 and Py3, while calling `reader.next()`/`reader.__next__()` obviously works only with one or the other.

Comment: @abarnert -- Yeah, I thought they made that change in 3.0 ( I was just too lazy to go look it up so I fell back on the easier -- but less robust -- "idiomatic" argument )